# How to construct an isogeny in SageMath from rational functions

Tags: sage

I am trying to construct the isogeny described in Example 2.5 of [this paper](https://pages.ramapo.edu/%7Ekmcmurdy/research/McMurdy-ssEndoRings.pdf) in SageMath, but as far as I can tell (say from [this post](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/59344/instantiating-elliptic-curve-isogenies-using-rational-maps/)), there is no way to directly construct an isogeny from its rational maps.

The suggested workaround in the second linked post is to pass the kernel polynomial as a lone parameter into `E.isogeny()`, but I am getting an error when trying that. Here's a MWE showing the error:

```
sage: R.<x,y,z,t> = PolynomialRing(GF(43), 4)
sage: E1 = EllipticCurve(y^2 - (x^3 - 14*x^2 - 6*x + 17))
sage: f = (x-37)^2*(x-40)^2
sage: E1.isogeny(f)
```

and I get an error saying that I have invalid parameters for the isogeny constructor. Where is this error coming from, and how can I construct the isogeny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sage doesn't accept multivariate polynomials as kernel polynomials. Use `.univariate_polynomial()` to convert f:

```
sage: R.<x,y,z,t> = PolynomialRing(GF(43), 4)
E1 = EllipticCurve(y^2 - (x^3 - 14*x^2 - 6*x + 17))
sage: f = (x-37)^2*(x-40)^2
sage: E1.isogeny(f.univariate_polynomial())
```

Note however that that particular polynomial does not define an isogeny.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the note! I suppose the paper does say "degree 5 map" rather than "degree 5 isogeny", so I should have been more careful in my wording. Much obliged.